# MS Access nested subforms link to main (parent) form

Tags: ms-access, subforms

I am busy developing an MS Access 2007 application that requires the use of subforms with quite a complex user interface. I am aware on how to create a parent form and link to a subform so that it shows data relating to the parent form record, but my question is this:

If I have multiple nested subforms (say 3 or 4 levels down), can I somehow link a subform sitting on the 4th level with the record of the parent form on the 1st level? What I mean by nested subforms is having a form pasted inside a form, pasted inside another form, etc.

The subform that I wish to link with the parent form is currently using a query as its source object and the reason for using nested subform is purely for the aesthetics of the user interface.

Is there a simple way to go about this? Or perhaps using VBA?

Comment: I've never designed nested sbuforms and I feel this would be exceedingly confusing to the user.  I have created drill down forms many times where the subform "drills down" to another form with a subform which in turn "drills down" and frequently with a tab control to separate the data.   An example being a customer form with an invoices subform.   Then the invoices subform opens an invoices form which has a parts sbuform.  Which in turn opens up a parts form with various subforms

Answer (score 5):

One thing that many people don't realize is that the LinkChild/LinkMaster fields can actually be any valid expression. So, you could have subForm1's LinkChild/LinkMaster properties be:

```
  LinkMaster  CustomerID
  LinkChild   CustomerID
```

Then subForm2 could have this:

```
  LinkMaster  subForm1.Form!InvoiceID
  LinkChild   InvoiceID
```

...and so forth. I can't imagine going much deeper than that, but it's possible.

You might also consider if a cascading datasheet form might do the trick, using subdatasheets. You can even have a datasheet display a non-datasheet form as its subdatasheet (something I disconvered entirely accidentally when I switched a a parent form having a subform into datasheet view -- the subform remained displayed in form view). With subdatasheets, you don't have any issues with number of forms, or the limitation on embedding continuous forms.

Comment: Thanks for that. What I ended up doing was linking the top 3 level forms to the same recordset that the parent form was linked to, and then linked the fields on the 4th level with those on the 3rd. Pretty simple solution actually, but took me long enough to get my head around it..

Answer (score 0):

If this is purely for aesthetic reasons (it looks pretty to you or someone else), rather than functional reasons, why not just use a rectangle, with a "Sunken" Special Effect?